# Mysql Trigger syntax error why?

Tags: mysql, triggers, syntax-error

```
delimiter /
create trigger nuovoattore
after insert on attori
for each row
when ( 1970 > ( select year(AnnoNascita)
                from attori
                where cod_attore=new.cod_attore))
begin
delete from attori
where cod_attore=new.cod_attore;
end;/
```

Comment: my teacher say when was supported in mysql downvoto to he no me xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `WHEN` clause. Try:

```
delimiter /
create trigger nuovoattore
after insert on attori
for each row
begin
    if 1970 > ( select year(AnnoNascita)
                from attori
                where cod_attore=new.cod_attore)
    then 
        delete from attori
        where cod_attore=new.cod_attore;
    end if;
end;/
```